# ¿Que significa la palabra operator en la firma de una función?

Tags: c#

Porque la funcion de abajo tiene como nombre un String (operador) y un simbolo (+) ?   que clase de firma es esta?

```
public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2)
{
return new Complex
{
Real = c1.Real + c2.Real,
Imaginary = c1.Imaginary + c2.Imaginary
};
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto se usa para sobrecargar un operador que trabaje sobre las clases que sirven como parametros.

En este caso, se usa para poder sumar 2 numeros complejos.

De esta forma, el siguiente codigo es valido

```
Complex c1 = new Complex();
Complex c2 = new Complex();
Complex c3 = c1+c2;
```

Si no existiera eso, el operador + tiraria un error si quisieras sumar esas dos clases, ya que el programa no sabria como hacer eso (el compilador ya tiraria el error).

referencia [aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading)

Comment: entonces seria para sobrecargar, se utiliza para otro caso mas?

Comment: no que yo sepa...

Comment: entonces esa firma solo serviria para + - * / y demas operadores, a lo mucho 15 casos?

Comment: Fijate en la tabla del enlace que pase.. pero si.. tampoco es que hay muchos mas operadores...